# Controlling tile animations on the Start Screen

Tags: microsoft-metro

I'm using the [TileSquarePeekImageAndText02](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx#TileSquarePeekImageAndText04) template to display some information on the tile. Right now, I believe the tile is alternating between the two *states* every 10 seconds. Is there a way to control this setting? I want it swap the tiles every 5 seconds. Here's the XML for the tile --

```
<tile>
  <visual>
    <binding template="TileSquarePeekImageAndText04">
      <image id="1" src="image1" alt="alt text"/>
      <text id="1">Text Field 1</text>
    </binding>  
  </visual>
</tile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Windows determines and controls when items are animated on the Start screen.  The animations are coordinated between all of the tiles to make cycling, peek tiles, and new tile update animations not all occur at once, providing a smoother user experience.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Another quick question if you don't mind - is there an event I can hook into that will tell me when the user made the tile wider/smaller? I need to disable the badge when in wide mode.

Comment: No, that isn't exposed to the app.