# How to develop Moving tiles (switch content)

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, tiles

I need to create a moving tiles in application windows 8 metro. The tiles must alternate showing a text for 3 secondes and switch to show image for 5 secondes like in the dektop of windows8.
How can i do this please??

Best regards

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12737105/1656796.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do this , because the display time of live tile is determined by OS.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the timing TileWidePeekImageAndText01 does exactly the same. It shows a picture than a text and just loop every 2-3 seconds.

[Tile template cataloge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx)